# Prove that $\frac{2\pi i}{f'(z_0)} = \int_C \frac{1}{f(z)-f(z_0)}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

This is Lang Complex Analysis Chapter V.1 #1. We are given that $f$ is analytic on an open subset $U$ and $f'(z_0) \neq 0$. The curve $C$ is some small circle centered at $z_0$. I think I need to use Cauchy's formula but the integral is confusing me. Looking for any hints!

Answer (score 1):

Applying Residue theorem : $$ \int_{\mathscr{C}}{\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{f\left(z\right)-f\left(z_{0}\right)}}=2\pi\mathrm{i}\,\mathrm{Res}\left(z\mapsto\frac{1}{f\left(z\right)-f\left(z_{0}\right)},z_{0}\right)=2\pi\mathrm{i}\lim_{z\to z_{0}}{\frac{z-z_{0}}{f\left(z\right)-f\left(z_{0}\right)}}=\frac{2\pi\mathrm{i}}{f'\left(z_{0}\right)} $$

Comment: Although this may be correct, we have not so far covered the residue theorem and that is actually in the next chapter. Is there another way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Just apply the residue theorem.  The residue at $z_0$ is $1/f'(z_0)$.

Comment: We haven't covered the residue theorem yet; it's in the next chapter